# How to make rectangles collide and bounce back a little in processing?

Tags: processing

So I have this code and I want the rectangles to collide and bounce off each other and reverse direction. Also I want one of the rectangles to be going faster than the other. How would I accomplish this? Here is my code:

```
//*******************************************
//Declare Variables
//*******************************************
float mov = 0.0; //movement
int dir = 1; //direction
int off = 50; //offset4cornerMode

void setup() {
size(200,200);
}
void draw() {
fill(255,0,0);
rect(width-off-mov,mov, 50,50);
fill(0,0,255);
rect(mov,mov, 50,50);
if(mov > width-off || mov < 0) {
dir *= -1;
}
mov+=1*dir;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do collisions is to check at each frame whether the extents of either rectangle overlap with the other. If this is true then run a function which calculates the new velocity of each shape and sets it. In your example you've just flipped the velocity.

To be able to change the velocity more easily I'd recommend making a class such as:

```
class Rectangle{
  float velocityX;
  float positionX;
  float width;
  float height;


}


Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle();
Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle();
step = 0.01;

void setup(){
rect1.positionX = 0;
rect1.velocityX = 10;
rect1.width = 10;
rect1.height = 10;

rect2.positionX = 100;
rect2.velocityX = -20;
rect2.width = 10;
rect2.height = 10;
}
```

This can be expanded with methods called something like collide which sets the new velocity from the old one.

For more info on a realistic collision between to objects the top you should read up on is **Elastic Collisions in One Dimension**